# Stuck in tty1 login console

Tags: login, tty, nvidia-settings

I am stuck in tty1 login console. I get the tty1 login screen after logging in the tty1 console with my username and password. It seems like it is in a loop. What shall I do?

Comment: Entering the correct username and password combination didn't help?

Comment: Control-Alt-F7 will get you back to the GUI, maybe try rebooting from there if possible?

Comment: Correct username and password did not help.